# handle confidential data and text in Android app

Tags: android, encryption

What would be the best most secure way to handle confidential text in an Android app?

The basic structure is (text/int) and some similar variations of it.

The app only shows a selection of the (readable text /readable int) at a time, so decryption will only be done for very few pairs at a time.

I need to make sure that extracting the complete (text/int) information is practically impossible - if possible :-)

Is there any standard library/scheme to handle this?

Many thanks

> EDIT (after getting some very interesting responses to this question):

It seems that even when the data is encrypted one could easily take the de-compiled code from the app, combine this with a self-written extraction routine, and hereby get all the decrypted info to a file.  Since the encryption key has to be provided to users of the app, everybody could potentially get to the data this way.

So in summary there is no real good solution?

Comment: Can you, please, explain more from who you want to protect your text?

Comment: You should think about how to secure your encryption key. What's the use of encrypting this stuff if anyone who picks up the device can go into your app and read it? Are you going to prompt for a password inside your app?

Comment: actually I want to protect it from anybody trying to get this valuable info - since this would be useful to many other apps in the same area, like certain kind of vocabularies. - Regarding the encryption key! this is actually a very valid point - up until now I used my own encryption class - but this can be relatively easy be reverse-engineered on Android I found out - just by decompiling the app code one can get lots of info easily- I was really astonished. It's not like that in C/C++. Everybody who has the password could potentially easily decode all info then, I have to find an alternative!

Comment: Keep in mind that even if you use C/C++ it can easily be reverse engineered by someone with sufficient skill. But yes, it's *very* easy if it's in Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your application you can use a symmetric cryptography and you can store your key in the Keystore. This key should be protected with password. Every time, when you run your application, it will ask the user for the password. If the password is correct then the key is extracted from the Keystore and used to decrypt your data. In this case, there is no difference where you store your data (text/int pairs) because all data will be encrypted. For Android SDK look at the package java.security and to the class java.security.KeyStore

If you want to supply your application with the data that you don't want to be extracted then obfuscation is a possible solution if you write in Java. If you want this functionality to be written in C/C++ then use Android NDK.

Comment: If I do understand you correctly, then one could still get the encryption key through the password (which I need to provide to all users anyway) relatively easily. And with the encryption key one can get to the data...

Comment: If a user has access to the decrypted data (even one pair) then she/he can simply copy all decrypted pairs one by one (either using a script or simply one by one). As I understand you want just to harden this process. If it is so then as I proposed you can put this functionality into native code (C/C++ code using NDK) and try to conceal extraction of the data there. Disassembling is harder then disobfuscation.

Comment: OK, I understand now what you are saying! Doing native C seems to be the best way to go here. By the way, could you please explain when you say: "If a user has access to the decrypted data (even one pair) then she/he can simply copy all decrypted pairs..." How? Why?

Comment: If you display decrypted data to a user he/she can always copy that data (for instance, he/she can type the same data in another file on his/her computer). This is the basic problem of all DRM approaches.

Comment: ...so you mean, the user could "generate" all decrypted entries by locking into the appropriate app routine and somehow enumerate the entries? Anyway, never done this with Java, how easy/difficult would it be anyways to add own pieces of code to a de-compiled java app?

Comment: Using different tools (smali/backsmali or dedexer) you can easily decompile android application. After that it is possible to produce even Java code. So you can read it and correct it with ease. Obfuscation add some problems (for instance, it renames all classes like a.java with methods like b(), so the only problem is to understand semantics in the decompiled java application. With native code you cannot do smth like this. You can read assembler code of the native app but it is difficult to convert it into c/c++ code. So this native app will require more experience and efforts.

Comment: Actually, there is no perfect solution in your case. The ideal case, is to use approaches similar to web. If smb try sequentially read a lot of data you can block the reading for the amount of time. Of coarse, to harden the life of the hacker everything should be implemented using native code and using different techniques to prevent decompilation.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean with obfuscating the code - very nice idea in fact. Is there an tool available that does this on an Android project? Would be really nice to just say: "obfuscate projectName"! - Thanks!

Comment: Yep, there is a tool with Android SDK that do it. Read about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

Answer (score 2):

You can save your text/int pair into the SharedPreference.

Because it's not secure, you can encryt the data before saving it into the SharedPreference in the same way as Google do in the [Application Licensing](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html) package.

More details can be found in the [Implementing an Obfuscator](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#impl-Obfuscator) part.

The code source of the [AESObfuscator](http://code.google.com/p/marketlicensing/source/browse/library/src/com/android/vending/licensing/AESObfuscator.java) can be found in the SDK in the market_licensing/library/src/com/android/vending/licensing folder.